# Kotlin - Interface Delegation at runtime

Tags: java, android, kotlin, delegates

I have a interface like this

```
interface A{
  fun test()
}
```

i  have a class B1 which implements A

```
class B1: A
{
    override fun test()
  {
          print("B1")
   }
}
```

Same like B1

```
class C1: A
{
    override fun test()
  {
    print("C1")
  }
}
```

And i have a class A1 which implements A

```
  class A1 (var test : Test) : A by test
{
      init
  {
      // Based on condition  i need to decide the delegation either B1 or C1
  }
}
fun main(){
A1(B1()) // By default am sending the object of B1
}
```

My problem is i need to change the delegation at runtime in init based on some condition.
is there is any way to do like that?

Answer (score 1):

You may have an expression in the `A1 : A by expression` syntax. The expression is evaluated *before* the class construction is completed. The delegation syntax does not allow one to switch implementations.

You may still code that manually, or use any dynamic proxy libraries, e.g. CGLib, ButeBubuddy. There is `java.land.reflect.Proxy` class, that is included in the JVM, you may consider using it as well. But it has side effects with checked exceptions https://jonnyzzz.com/blog/2018/11/22/proxy/

The last alternative is to generate code at the compile time. KotlinPoet can be helpful for that. You may include that task into your maven or Gradle build. The benefit is that you will control how the delegation works, and you will not waste time for that when the code is running
https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't think it's worth doing this using the `by` delegation keyword. Instead, I would just internally store a `private var` for `A` inside `A1` and manually forward the calls. Something like:

```
class A1 : A {
    private var aDelegate: A

    init { 
        aDelegate = if (condition) B1() else C1()
    }

    override fun test() {
        aDelegate.test()
    }
}
```

That said, there is an option that you could use, although I wouldn't necessarily recommend it. It requires surfacing a custom mutable implementation of `A` to callers of `A1`, but is left optional so that it doesn't have to be used:

```
class MutableA(var aDelegate: A = EmptyA()) : A {
    override fun test() {
        aDelegate.test()
    }

    class EmptyA : A { 
        override fun test() { }
    }
}

class A1(private val mutableA: MutableA = MutableA()) : A by delegate {
    init {
        mutableA.aDelegate = if (condition) B1() else C1()
    }
}
```

So you could initialize it, as an example, like:

```
class A1(flag: Boolean, private val mutableA: MutableA = MutableA()) : A by delegate {
    init { 
        mutableA.aDelegate = if (flag) B1() else C1()
    }
}

fun main() {
    A1(true).test() // prints "B1"
    A1(false).test() // prints "C1"
}
```